# How to load avro files from blob storage to azure data factory MOVING DATA FLOW?

Tags: avro, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage, azure-eventhub

How to load avro files from blob storage to azure data factory MOVING DATA FLOW?
I'm trying to load but unable to import schema and preview. 
My avro files in blob are result of event hub capture function. 
I have to move data from azure blob to azure sql db using azure data factory's moving data flow.

Answer (score 1):

Data Factory support [Avro files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/supported-file-formats-and-compression-codecs).

In Data Flow, create a new Source from Azure Blob Storage:
[image]

Choose the Avro format for your files:
[image]

Choose the file path:

[image]

Then you can add the sink to Azure SQL dataset:

[image]

Here is another tool may be helpful for you: [Load AVRO Files Data to Azure SQL Database in Real Time](https://www.striim.com/integrations/avro-azure-sql-database/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have used event hub capture function and loaded into azure blob storage. In azure blob storage it is stored in .avro format. Next when I'm trying to access these files as source in moving data flow ( azure data factory), it is not able to preview the data. Once can you check loading such files in adf moving data flow

Comment: Yes, I know your meanings. But not all format data can be preview in data flow, that's the limitation in Data Flow(preview). You can find many blogs talked about this in stack overflow. Data Factory didn't give us more information about this. But we still can transfer the data.

Comment: Hi @karthik, If my answer is helpful for you, please accept(mark) it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.